# How do I list processes in htop by just their name, without the full path?

Tags: linux, top

Is there a way to have the list of processes in htop only display as the name of the command, rather than the full pathname w/ flags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an update, now apparently there is an option in Setup/DisplayItems `Show Program Path` that is checked by default. Just need to uncheck that so only the command name is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not.  You can however go to Setup/DisplayItems to Highlight the basenames.

It doesn't only list the command like you want, but it atleast makes it a little more visible.

Comment: Ah. The highlighting helps a lot. Thx. Seems sort of dumb to not provide an option for basename-only listings, though -- it's extremely noisy the way it is now.

Comment: There's a PR in htop github that may help resolving this issue some day: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/pull/184

Answer (score 3):

To make htop display only nginx processes:

```
htop -p $(pgrep nginx | paste -s -d,)
```

Comment: `htop -p $(pgrep nginx | paste -s -d, )`
the space before the last closed bracket is important else the command gives an error `htop: option requires an argument -- 'p'` in my case. Second, the mentioned error occurs, when no process of this name is running at all

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @mfink answer.

When you open **htop**, press **F2**, then scroll to **Display options**, left arrow, scroll down to **Show program path** and uncheck with space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to previous answers, that pointed to `F2/Display Options/Show program path`.

You can **toggle this on/off by pressing p** in the main screen of `htop`.